# How to remove specific line including its newline in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my code:

```js
console.log("before:");
let str = "aaa bbb\nbbb ccc\naaa bbb\b";
console.log(str);
console.log("after:");
console.log(str.replace(/^bbb.*$/gm, ''));
```

I need such output:

```
before:
aaa bbb
bbb ccc
aaa bbb
after:
aaa bbb
aaa bbb
```

I tried to do this way:

```
console.log(str.replace(/^bbb.*[\r|\n]$/gm, ''));
```

but it didn't help. How to do it, taking into consideration that I need to remove only lines (that start with `bbb`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `\n` to end of regex pattern to selecting newline. So the pattern should change to `/^bbb.*$\n?/gm`

```js
console.log("before:");
let str = "aaa bbb\nbbb ccc\naaa bbb\n";
console.log(str);
console.log("after:");
console.log(str.replace(/^bbb.*$\n?/gm, ''));
```

Comment: `/^bbb.*$\n/gm` won't work if the line is the last line.

Answer (score 1):

The regex just needs a tweak:

`str.replace(/^bbb.+\n/gm, '');`

Works:

```js
console.log("before:");
let str = "aaa bbb\nbbb ccc\naaa bbb\b";
console.log(str);
console.log("after:");
console.log(str.replace(/^bbb.+\n/gm, ''));
```

Comment: I did say - I need to remove only lines - only lines that start with `bbb`.

Comment: So I see! OK, tweaked to satisfy that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of your last line :

`console.log(str.replace(/^bbb.*$/gm, '').replace(/(^[ \t]*\n)/gm, ""));`

Answer (score 0):

The empty line in the output is generated by `\n`. So, to remove it, you just need to replace `\n` with `''`.

```js
console.log("before:");
let str = "aaa bbb\nbbb ccc\naaa bbb\b";
console.log(str);
console.log("after:");
console.log(str.replace(/bbb\s\w+\n/, ''));
```

Because there is 1 substring that contains `bbb`, follows by a white space, some alphabet characters and `\n`, we don't need to use *starts with* (`^`) and *ends with* (`$`). Just replacing the matched substring. `gm` could also be removed, too.